# Procedimiento almacenado en mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Hola muchachos buenos días nuevamente aquí con nuevas dudas.

Estoy haciendo un mantenerdor en java Desktop y en la parte de búsqueda tengo una campo de texto en donde ingresaría el valor a buscar, pero además tengo unos radiobuttons que me permitieran elegir el campo de mi tabla en qué buscar.

Me explico: Tengo una tabla de proveedores con 3 campos: nombre, pais, region. Entonces en mi aplicación tengo una caja de texto donde ingreso el valor a buscar, pero además los radiobuttons me permiten elegir entre si buscar en el campo nombre o en el campo pais o en el campo región.

Entonces mi SP en Mysql lo hice así:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE listarProveedores(campo varchar(50), valor varchar(50))
BEGIN
  select * from suppliers where campo like concat('%',valor,'%');
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Y cuando llamo al SP:

```
CALL listarProveedores('ContactName','ch');
```

no me muestra nada.

Favor de que alguien me dé una opción.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Carlos, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te preguntaría ¿por qué un SP y no una consulta normal la cual podrías construir dinámicamente según los valores necesarios? También, sería bueno que pusieras el código Java que estás usando y que indiques el resultado: error (qué mensaje de error), datos vacíos, etc.

Comment: Primero que todo el procedimiento no definido una variable de salida OUT, y segundo, concat() es para concatenar caracteres, esa consulta debería estar arronjando un error porque cuando esta se interprete daría como resultado:

     `select * from suppliers where 'el_campo' like 'el_valor'; `

Lo que sería un error de sintaxis

Comment: Buenas tardes y muchas gracias por su respuesta.
Estoy utilizando un SP porque me parece que es más adecuado que una consulta normal. 
Y lo que deseo que me arroje el SP es una lista de registros que hacen alusión a los proveedores que tengo almacenados en mi BD.
Pd. Estoy utilizando Northwind como BD.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que las variables del procedimiento no las puedes incluir en la SQL como tal. La solución a tu problema es un prepared statement. Se podría hacer algo así:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE listarProveedores(campo varchar(50), valor varchar(50))
BEGIN
    SET @buffer = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE ", campo, " LIKE %", valor, "%'");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @buffer;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

O lo podrias hacer a través de un CASE:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE listarProveedores(campo varchar(50), valor varchar(50))
BEGIN
  CASE campo
     WHEN 'a' THEN SELECT * FROM suplliers WHERE a LIKE CONCAT('%',valor,'%');
     WHEN 'b' THEN SELECT * FROM suplliers WHERE b LIKE CONCAT('%',valor,'%');
     WHEN 'c' THEN SELECT * FROM suplliers WHERE c LIKE CONCAT('%',valor,'%');
  END CASE;
 END
 $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Gracias amigo! Un abrazo